# My intention is (to finish/to have finished) my studies by June

Tags: grammaticality, perfect-aspect

1. My intention is to finish my studies by June.
2. My intention is to have finished my studies by June.

Is it correct to say 1 or 2? If both are correct, are there any differences between them?

Comment: 1)  intention: to finish, not yet done 2) intention: to have finished, viewing what some after to finish as a completed action. That is the difference in feeling.

Answer (score -1):

1 is correct since the statement is more of simple future

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct.
Although they both *feel* different, I cannot, as a native speaker, articulate any difference in meaning. I would treat them the same.

Answer (score -1):

As Lambie noted in the comments, both are acceptable, but there's a subtle distinction between the two.

> My intention is to finish my studies by June.

Should be read as:

> I'm studying now and hope to be done by the time June arrives.

While:

> Right now, my intention is to have finished my studies by June.

Carries the connotation of you *reflecting on your accomplishment and efforts at a future point in time (once June arrives), and afterwards moving on to other things*. So you could read it as:

> When June arrives, I'll hopefully already be finished with my studies.

Answer (score -2):

"My intention on studies is by June to get me credentialed." No ands, if's, or but's. Credentials even diploma is my life and is not to be tampered with and placed or misplaced somewhere on a bucket list's. 
Studies seems as a never ending indulging predicament in the short run, and happily forever we learn and rather then we die.